# Update multiple rows of a table having specific value in particular column equal to value calculated from two other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have three tables . I want to update **TableC** rows which have column `Price=0`

**Table A**

```
StoreId rate
1       100   
2       200
```

**TableB**

```
ProductId StoreId
11           1
22           2
30           1
40           1
67           2
```

**TableC**

```
ProductID Quantity Price
11           20     0
22           30     6000
30           100    0 
40           200    0
67           370    0
```

I want to update TableC rows which have Price=0 by multiplying Quantity (obtained from Table C ) with Rate ( obtained from TableA ) linked by TableB

Now my confusion is below approach will work if I have to update single row of TableC

```
declare @rate int,declare @qty int

select @rate =rate , @qty=quantity
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
   on a.storeId=b.storeId
inner join tableC c
   on b.productId=c,productId
--where c.productId=somevalue --one row returned
-- where c.Price=0  -- returns multiple row -- update wont work
```

Comment: When working with a SQL database, you should always think in terms of updating a set, not a single row. That's why JW's solution below makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly update `TableC` by joining `TableB` and `TableC` on it.

```
UPDATE  c
SET     c.Price = c.Quantity * a.Rate
FROM    TableC c
        INNER JOIN TableB b
            ON c.ProductID = b.ProductID
        INNER JOIN TableA a
            ON b.StoreID = a.StoreID
WHERE   c.Price = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ec91/1)

Comment: let me try this out , question posted is a highly simplified version of what i am trying to implement but I hope Caption JW will guide my sinking ship through the stormy sea of tsql ..